# I have a game in Netbeans that uses JOptionPane.showOptionDialog and i dont know how to do the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

below is my code Stud is player but the if (Stud.equals("North")) is saying it cant compare is there another way to compare them?

```
String[] options = new String[] {"North", "South", "East", "West"}; 

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, p + " " + Stud.distance(Comp) + " away" +  
    " Which way do you want to move?", "" + p + " is at " + Stud.getX() + ", " + Stud.getY() ,  
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, options, options[0]);

if (options.equals("North")){ 
    Stud.moveNorth();   
}
else if (options.equals("South")){
    Stud.moveSouth();
}
else if (options.equals("West")){
    Stud.moveWest();
}
else if (options.equals("East")){
    Stud.moveSouth();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `int compareTo(String anotherString)`

Also the JOptionPane returns a value that you need to store.

Like this

```
int optionChosen = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, p + " " + Stud.distance(Comp) + " away" +  
    " Which way do you want to move?", "" + p + " is at " + Stud.getX() + ", " + Stud.getY() ,  
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, options, options[0]);

if (options[optionChosen].compareTo("North") == 0){ 
    Stud.moveNorth();   
}
```

or, you could make this much more simple, and use the `int` returned by the JOptionPane to make the choice of directions.

Like this:

```
if (optionChosen == 0){ 
    Stud.moveNorth();   
}
else if(optionChosen == 1){
    Stud.moveSouth();
}
...and so on.
```